# IIS Redirects Migrating part of a web app

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have an app which i'm moving to a new server in stages

e.g.

www.sausages.com/directory/directory2/home.aspx

Everything in www.sausages.com/directory/directory2
will be on my new server.

however everything else will need to point back to my old server.

Is their any nice simple method to achieve this?

Comment: If your site depends on session variables, you'll have more work to do instead of just the rewrites mentioned by Carlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, URL Rewrite is a very simple way to achieve that:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You can very easily write a rule that matches the directory you want and redirect for it with a 301.

I wrote a blog a few years ago where you could have individual URLs if needed to remap them easily:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2011/08/13/razor-migration-notes-2-use-url-rewrite-to-maintain-your-page-rankings-seo.aspx

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

Comment: thankyou you has the parameter i wanted which was "negate"